# Having trouble hosting multiple sites on the same IP on a web server

Tags: virtual-machines, web-hosting, azure

For the sake of keeping it simple, let's say I have 2 sites on my VM.  The first site is www.mltsolutions.com and the second site is www.boxfetch.com.  Here's my IIS on the server:

[image]

Focusing on www.boxfetch.com, here are the site bindings:

[image]

The IP address is the internal IP for the server.  I have a simple index.html page for testing located in the root directory.  Here's where I have my web content for my sites, which I've appropriately mapped to in IIS:

[image]

Finally, I configured my DNS settings for www.boxfetch.com as having an A record (*) that points to the public IP for my web server.  When this is set like this, accessing the website brings up the content under Default Web Site in IIS.  So, I would imagine I need to do something like *.boxfetch.com instead of a wildcard `*`.  I tried this but I get an "Unresolved DNS error", even after waiting the propagation period.  Here's my DNS:

[image]

**QUESTION**: I want to obviously host multiple sites on one IP.  Am I following the correct path?  Anything you see off hand that I'm doing wrong?  I feel like I need to be doing something else in IIS.

Comment: The name of the IIS feature escapes me at the moment, but don't you need something like an .htaccess to define virtual sites?

Comment: Never heard of needing that, but I'm new to this, so that doesn't mean anything :)

Comment: Does it work if you add a CNAME for "www" as the hostname and point it to "domain.com" as the address?

Comment: I need to route both www.boxfetch.com and boxfetch.com to the same place, and from my research doing a CNAME you can't use wildcards.  So, while www may work, it'll only work if the user does www.boxfetch.com and will not work if they do boxfetch.com.  Does this make any sense? @NathanC

Comment: Plus, without defining the Host Name in DNS, how will the routing know to go to the right directory in IIS? @NathanC

Comment: Have a quick read of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting and see if that clears your issue up a bit.

Comment: @tombull89 The only thing that really stood out to me as something I may not be doing correctly is setting the Host Name Header.  Wouldn't this be the same as setting Host Name in the Bindings section of the website in IIS?

Comment: @MikeMarks sorry I can't help, don't use IIS myself.

Answer (score 1):

1. DNS doesn't propagate.
2. Create an A record for boxfetch.com and for www.boxfetch.com that resolves to your public ip address.
3. Add boxfetch.com to the web site bindings for the boxfetch web site.
4. Do the same thing for the other web site.

Comment: So are you saying that DNS changes are automatic?  I added 2 Host A records, one for boxfetch.com and one for www.boxfetch.com, pointed to the public IP.  I went to the site bindings, and changed the Host Name from www.boxfetch.com to boxfetch.com for the binding on port 80.  Still same problem.

Comment: Correction, now boxfetch.com works but www.boxfetch.com doesn't work.

Comment: DNS records don't propagate. If you create a new DNS record it is available immediately to all hosts that request it. If you update a record then those hosts that have that record cached will wait until the TTL of the record expires before looking up the record again. At no time do your DNS records get propagated. They get cached, but only by hosts that request them. - Make sure that boxfetch.com and www.boxfeth.com point to the public ip address that gets "forwarded" to your internal web server ip address. Then stop and restart IIS and try them both again.

Comment: Ugh, I tried all this, same problem.  dns_server_failure.

Comment: A check of the boxfetch.com domain at DnsStuff shows no A record for the naked domain name and no A record for www.boxfetch.com. You need to check your DNS records again.